# what happen if i delete system.log file in magento 2?can create new empty system.log file?

Tags: magento2, log, system.log

> what happen if i delete the system.log file in Magento 2?
>
> can create a new empty system.log file?

could anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to worry the **system.log** file will be recreated automatically again when you reload your website. The var/log directory should have the proper write permission (0755/0777)

Comment: how i can reload my site

Comment: simply click the refresh button in your browser or press f5 key in your keyboard